# Transaction emails not being sent

Tags: email, payment-gateway

A week ago my transactions email were working just fine, but today they aren't. Since they were working I changed the email address they are being sent from, I've created my own templates and assigned them, and I got a new paymentgateway Epay. 
I think the problem may be the paymentgateway. I if look into my system.log i find the following error;

```
2014-09-28T11:23:25+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/epay/standard/email.phtml
```

Can this be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the Epay module? Then try again..

Comment: USAePay has a support number you can call. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to a bug in Epay version 2.6.
It was solved by updating my Epay module.